# discord.py: How to set a comma after a certain number of numbers?

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I want that if I use the command and type a number, the bot should send that number but with a `,` after a certain number of numbers.

For example:

```
@bot.command
async def number(ctx, arg1):
    # input for example: 1123456
    await ctx.send(f'{arg1}')
    # output: 1,123,456
```

Answer (score 0):

Use str.format(number) with "{:,}" as str to signal the use of a comma for a thousands separator and return a string with commas added to number.

Ex.

number_with_commas = "{:,}".format(1000000)

print(number_with_commas)

OUTPUT
1,000,000

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, check string. If size is bigger than 3, give for and every third place, add ","

Comment: can you give me an example please?